# How to identify sites using semantic web schemas?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, search-engine, semantic-web, schema.org

I'm developing a semantic web search engine based on schema.org.  My problem is figuring out how to efficiently index which websites use a particular schema - e.g. FoodEstablishment.

The goal is to identify/develop a mapping of domains to schemas, such that the description for a particular schema usage (*e.g.* `Usage: Between 1000 and 10,000 domains`) can be fully explicit.

---

**EDIT #1**

I was [recommended](http://qr.ae/7BDlpr) to consider building on top of [Web Data Commons](http://webdatacommons.org/) architecture, which is currently designed to identify a subset of schema.org classes.  This looks like a good starting point...

Comment: This question is likely too broad. Even asking an open question like that about only one of the three involved areas (crawling, scraping, processing) might be too broad. Maybe you could be more specific? Do you have already an idea how it could work?

Comment: Thanks, I understand.  I've updated with a relevant link to anyone else trying to also build such an architecture.  I will update with a more specific question if needed.